# Heat map which will be auto-updated from Google Docs

Tags: web-mapping, google-docs

I want to develop a heat map (standardized choropleth map) which will be auto-updated with data pulled from GoogleDocs. Which tools are the most helpful for developing that kind of map?

Comment: I think you're looking for Google Fusion Tables - There's an [API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/)

Comment: @Roy I am not sure that the fusion tables can be auto-updated (or even edited). Perhaps CartoDB would work?